# How to unpause thread in Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I want to know if there is a way to unpause a sleeping thread in Qt
I pause the thread using QThread::msleep(ms) function
And I want to unpause the thread before time runs out
Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: Could you provide more context for your question, why do you want to do this?  Are you trying to run two threads in parallel that access the same resource? If so just use mutexes, what do you mean "before time runs out", this is extremely vauge as it stands

Comment: have a look at `QMutex` and `QWaitCondition`

Comment: I have a class named SerialSender (implementation of QThread) that send data using QSerialPort, and there is a delay between each QSerialPort::write (using QThread::msleep), and i want to unpause the SerialSender thread to directly send data without waiting, what i want is to know if i can stop the QThread::msleep function execution ?

Comment: Why not create a timer with the delay you want it to have instead? Or if what you want is to wait for the data to be written then you have signal and slots for exactly that purpose so no need for messing with the thread

Comment: I'd have a signal to trigger when that thread should start, given that you can't precisely measure the time it takes your other process to complete.  Putting in a timer is a sort of lazy way of pausing execution, but you're actually going to be slowing your program down

Comment: @Alex you're right unless he requires a set interval of when the writing is triggered then a timer is perfectly acceptable. That's why I gave both ways. Apart from that in order to help you out creekorful we're going to need more information

Comment: @deW1 good point!  I didn't consider that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, If you are using `QSerialPort`, you really don't have to mess up with threads. You should deal with it asynchronously. So, you `read()` in slots connected to `readyRead()` signal, and if you want to have some delay between writes use a `QTimer` and `write()` in slots connected to its `timeout()` signal as suggested by @deW1's comment.

If you really want to go with multiple threads, @sploid's code approach has many mistakes:

A mutex has to be unlocked only by the thread that locked it. Here is what the [documentation for `QMutex::unlock()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmutex.html#unlock) says:

> Unlocks the mutex. **Attempting to unlock a mutex in a different thread to the one that locked it results in an error.** Unlocking a mutex that is not locked results in undefined behavior.

- A [`QMutex`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmutex.html#details) is used to protect an object, data structure or section of code so that only one thread can access it at a time. It is not used for a thread to *signal* some other thread.
- A [`QWaitCondition`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwaitcondition.html#details) allows a thread to tell other threads that some sort of condition has been met. This is what you need to use to tell the other thread to "*unpause*".

Here is how it should have been done:

```
class Thread : public QThread{
public:
    Thread(QObject* parent=nullptr):QThread(parent){

    }
    ~Thread(){}

    void InterruptWaitState(){
        QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
        cond.wakeAll();
    }

protected:
    void run(){
        //waiting thread
        QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
        if(cond.wait(&mutex, 5000)){
            // unlock from another place
        } else {
            // exit by timeout
        }
    }

private:
    QMutex mutex;
    QWaitCondition cond;
};
```

Answer (score -2):

```
QMutex mut;

void InterruptMethod() {
  mut.unlock();
}

void SleepMethod() {
  mut.lock();
  const int kTimeout = 5000;
  bool over_event_come = mut.tryLock(kTimeout); // here was sleep
  if (over_event_come) {
    // unlock from another place
  } else {
    // exit by timeout
  }
  mut.unlock();
}
```

Comment: please don't unlock a mutex from a thread other than the one that locked it. see my answer.